# MVC Ajax refresh interval text highlight changing values

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have made a MVC View with a partial view witch is refreshing every X seconds. That's works fine, but: I want to highlight the values that were changing. So if only 1 row are changing I want to highlight that row for a couple of seconds. Something like this: http://domajax.com/documentation/data-highlight-color (successes and errors).

My master view:

```
@using MovieStore.Domain.Entities

@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<Movie, TimeTable>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Actuele bezetting";
}

<h2>Bezetting voor vandaag</h2>

<div id="timetabel">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TimeTable", Model); }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function () {

        $("#timetabel").load('@(Url.Action("GetTimeTable","TimeTable",null, Request.Url.Scheme))');

    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Partial view:

```
@using MovieStore.Domain.Entities

@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<Movie, TimeTable>>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var group in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <h4>@group.Key.MovieName</h4>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr><td>Starttijd</td><td>Vrije plaatsen</td></tr>

                                @foreach (var tt in group)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@tt.StartTime.ToShortTimeString()</td>
                                        <td>@tt.SeatsAvaible</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

And the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var model = await GetTimeTabelModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> GetTimeTable()
        {
            var model = await GetTimeTabelModel();
            return PartialView("_TimeTable", model);
        }


        private async Task<IEnumerable<IGrouping<Movie, TimeTable>>> GetTimeTabelModel()
        {
            return timetablerepo.TimeTables.Where(tt => tt.StartTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).GroupBy(tt => tt.Movie);
        }
```

Comment: How do you identify which rows have changed since the previous call?

Comment: Not. I have zero jquery/javascript knowledge so I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you have property in the model (say) `LastEditedDate` to identify modified rows. Or are you referring to rows that have been added since the previous call

Comment: Nope. But I can add the LastEditedDate in the model. It is also possible to add rows.

Comment: I have added a LastEditedDate in Timetables with the DateTime when the row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Sounds like you really should be using [signalr](http://signalr.net/) to have the server push notifications of any change to the client rather than unnecessarily updating the page every 5 seconds.